# Not able to obtain complete files for app.scss in Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am currently trying to learn Laravel by following tutorial however when I perform `npm install` > `npm run dev` my `app.scss` folder is empty and I'm also missing the `variables.scss`?

[image: picture of visual studio code app.scss folder]

Please help! I have been searching google for the answer and nothing thus far.

Comment: The additional files were removed in the newly released Laravel 6.  You would need to install an appropriate Laravel version for your tutorial if you want a step-for-step experience. [Laravel 6 app.scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/sass/app.scss)   [Laravel 5.8 app.scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/resources/sass/app.scss)

Comment: After coming across some additional information, these features were split out into a separate package called `laravel/ui`, which can be installed with composer.

Answer (score 6):

You have to first install the Bootstrap and Vue scaffolding provided by Laravel which is located in the laravel/ui Composer package. Run the following to install:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

Once the laravel/ui package has been installed, you may install the frontend scaffolding using the ui Artisan command:

//to generate basic frontend scafollding

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react
```

You can also generate the login/registration scaffolding by appending "--auth" to either of the above. E.g

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.scss` is an empty file for you to implement your own style sheet. I don't think it comes with a `variables.scss` by default. You can simply create new scss files in the `/sass` folder and [@import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) it to your `app.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope am replying in time save a soul pertaining the same.
Follow these steps if you are using Laravel 6:

1. Make sure in /resources/js/app.js there you have this: `require('./bootstrap');`
2. Run on your terminal these commands:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install 
npm run dev
```

The public\css\app.css should now be present and you could now use Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

Same in my case too. I deleted node_module, clear the cache and re-installed npm, but again the same result. So, I copied the code of app.scss from another project and pasted it in the empty scss and now it is working fine.

Also, make sure that node env is not in production mode.